# How to restart virtual machine?

Tags: google-colaboratory

If I want to run another version of tensorflow or keras, then I can install the same with specific version. But after that I want to rollback to latest version, and install tensorflow again with latest version say 1.6.0rc, it is installing, but when I check the version again, it is still pointing to earlier version of tensorflow. How can I overwrite earlier version with latest one?

If I restart runtime, it is not affecting the software installed, it is only resetting application variables.

The other way is to restart the virtual machine itself, but how do I do that?

Or I need to close colab portal and wait for some time(not sure how long?) and then open the portal again with hope that it would start new virtual machine....

Any clarifications on these are greately appreciated

Answer (score 10):

To reset your backend, select the command 'Reset all runtimes...' from the Runtime menu.

[image]

Comment: I found an example that uses
`os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)`. Does this also work the same way? or differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart the entire VM with `!kill -9 -1`. Check this: [enter link description here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nGIZyvmGdyOXGLnBGx0JqSSt6PsXeim1#scrollTo=vwt)