# Google Colab broken with command: `!rm -rf /usr/local`

Tags: google-colaboratory

I tried installing MEEP in Google Colab and in doing so I ran the following command. Since the regular instructions for installation did not work, I tried this: [Installation instructions for MEEP on Google Colab Platform](https://github.com/stevengj/meep/issues/460#issuecomment-415649775)

Finally when I ran the following, that apparently messed up the whole environment.

`!rm -rf /usr/local`

Ever since I cannot run a single thing in Google Colab. Please suggest how I can fix this.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001921/how-to-restart-virtual-machine

Comment: @BobSmith: Thank you for responding. But I had tried `!kill -9 -1` earlier and it did not work then either. I don't know how but it looks like the environment got fixed somehow: whether it's by design to reset itself in every 24 hours to handle such instances or Google Colab-support fixed that I do not know. But I am so relieved!

Answer (score 0):

To drop your current backend and start fresh with a new one, select the command 'Reset all runtimes...' from the Runtime menu.

[image]

Comment: Than you @BobSmith. I will use this in future, if needed. I had asked the google colab support to fix it and apparently that fixed the environment. Now it is all operational again. So, I will not be able to test this as a solution.